# connect HTML Form to MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a block of code to submit my HTML form values to my Database using PHP via XAMPP. After construction and testing the record will saved in database successfully but I see a notice that says below:

> Undefined variable: localhost in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\30-11-2021\processhtml.php on line 19

Kindly see my line 19 below also:

```
$conn = new mysql ($localhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$conn =  new mysql ('localhost', $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

The first parameter is the hostname of the server running MySQL. In your case it's 'localhost'.

php warns you when you use an undefined variable, and gives the value `null` for that variable. In this context, a null hostname defaults to `localhost`, so that's why your code actually works.

Comment: Thank you it Worked.